# Visual Studio 11 Setup Projects

Tags: visual-studio-2012

According to Microsoft Visual Studio will no longer support setup projects, requiring instead that developers download and register for a light version of InstallShield.

Does anyone know if there are alternatives out there - WiX comes to mind but in a way this is like going assembly...

Comment: FYI, the product does not have an official name yet. When it does, it will not be "Visual Studio 2011" (a past year). The "11" in "Visual Studio 11" refers to the version number (Visual Studio 2010 was version 10; VS2008 was version 9).

Comment: @John Saunders - Thank you for the correction and edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wix. it is not like assembly, it wrocks - especially compared to installshield.

Otherwise no - before Wix came around installers where a bad area to be in anyway. Only buggy products, choose your pain between Installshield and Wise installer (now Symantec Altiris).

I prefer Wix any day over the other stuff.